# Как применить @Autowired к WebDriver?

Tags: java, spring

Использую `spring` и `selenium` в одном проекте, и приходится оборачивать `WebDriver` вот таким некрасивым способом:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class Firefox {

    @Getter
    private WebDriver driver;

    public Firefox() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

И все время приходится пользоваться геттером, что не очень приятно. Как можно добится того чтобы можно было писать вместо

```
@Autowired
private Firefox firefox;
```

И потом вызывать `firefox.getDriver()`

Настроить `spring` так что бы можно было сразу писать:

```
@Autowired
private WebDriver webDriver;
```

С учетом конечно того, что в классе `WebDriver` аннотацию `@Component` не как не поставить, так как он библиотечный.

Сейчас конфиг выглядит так:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.example"})
public class SpringBeansConfigurationInjector {

    @Scope("singleton")
    @Bean(name = "firefox")
    Firefox firefox() {
        return new Firefox();
    }
}
```

Comment: Что мешает объявить `@Bean WebDriver webDriver() { return new FirefoxDriver(); }` в вашей spring конфигурации?

Comment: @Nofate♦ а разве `@Component` не является обязательной для `@ComponentScan` которая будет искать в указанном пакете? Обновил вопрос.

Comment: `@ComponentScan` будет искать `@Component`-классы. Но `@Bean` просто поместит `WebDriver` в спринговый контекст и сделает доступным для `@Autowired`.

Comment: Аннотация `@Scope("singleton")` избыточна. В спринге все по-умолчанию имеет этот scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перепишите конфиг так:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.example"})
public class SpringBeansConfigurationInjector {

    @Bean
    WebDriver webDriver() {
        return new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

Теперь вы можете в любом другом классе, управляемом Spring-ом внедрить `WebDriver`:

```
package org.example;

@Component
public class SomeClass {
    @Autowired
    private WebDriver webDriver;
}
```